# Create cv::Mat vector as clone

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an input vector to my function and want to make sure I create the exact same type of vector (`16UC1` vs `8UC1`) and I do this by simply creating `cv::Mat myNewMat(myOldMat.clone())`

However, I want to create a vector of images and I currently do this with `cv::Mat myVectorOfMats[3]`. If I want to create a vector of `Mat`s which are exact copies of `myOldMat`, how would I do this?

Comment: As a quick solution: wrap it in a class. Call `cv::Mat::clone()` in its copy constructor.

Comment: You have 3 Mat, you could clone each one of them... `for (int i=0; i<3;i++) myNewMat[i](myOldMat[i].clone();`  Didn't actually test it...